# How can I replace IntegrityError throughout an application using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is some example code to demonstrate the setup:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, CheckConstraint
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'model'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    b = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('a != b', name='not_equal'),
        CheckConstraint('a != 1', name='not_one'),
    )


engine = create_engine(...)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Here is a demonstration that adding models that fail a constraint to a `session` in a transaction just throws `IntegrityError`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

engine = create_engine(...)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True)()

try:
    with session.begin():
        model = Model()
        model.a = 1
        model.b = 2
        session.add(model)
except IntegrityError as e:
    print(e)

try:
    with session.begin():
        model = Model()
        model.a = 2
        model.b = 2
        session.add(model)
except IntegrityError as e:
    print(e)
```

I know that I can extract the details of the `IntegrityError` once I've caught it so that I can raise my own exception.

What I can't figure out is how to handle the `IntegrityError` at a low enough level that my actual application logic doesn't have to deal with it. In other words, I would prefer a setup that allows for code like

```
try:
    with session.begin():
        model = Model()
        model.a = 1
        model.b = 2
        session.add(model)
except NotOneError as e:
    print(e)
```

Is there some way I can attach the error wrapping code to the model definition or to the session?

Comment: You could build a `Mixin` for your tables, in a similar way than [this recipe](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject) from `sqlalchemy` wiki. But anyway, let me tell you I don't think it is a good idea, I think your application logic should deal with an `IntegrityError`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think that approach works when using the session the way I'm using it. It looks like `IntegrityError` doesn't get thrown during the construction of the object, only when adding it to the session. Do you think there's a way to work with this on the session level?

Comment: Well, in the recipe of the link you don't really add objects to the session, but use instead the method `as_unique` to create the object -then the method adds it to the session internally. I was suggesting you could do something like that. If by your question you mean overriding the session object to modify `add`, I guess you could do that as well. But I would go for the first approach.